# Deleting Footnotes in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, footnote

I'm working on a document in Word 2007.  Somehow, when I was moving things around, a phantom footnote was introduced.  (See attached image.)  I have not been able to delete it.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to beginning of document.
2. Click the References tab.
3. Click Show Notes.
4. Click Next Footnote until the cursor moves to a position where a footnote does not exist.
5. That is the phantom footnote.
6. Delete the next around the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Providing you haven't made a lot of changes since, undo (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>) always fixes things like these :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not see a Next Footnote option in Word 365. But I realized that what happened is that the text of the endnotes was deleted but the endnotes themselves were left intact. The endnote numbers were particularly phantom-like because the Find utility doesn't find footnote or endnote numbers. But by manually searching the text where the sequential endnote numbers should be, I found them and was able to delete them. This also deleted the blank endnotes themselves.

Answer (score 0):

After spending (way too much) time, I realized I was editing my document using *track changes*... Aaaand I found out that if I switched view to seeing *All markup* I was able to see - and delete - my already deleted (and hence invisible) footnotes.

Bloody hell...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Turn on the Show/hide feature. Search through the document for the 'hidden' footnotes in the body of the text and delete.